# DirectX9 texture flashing or disappearing

Tags: textures, directx9

I am learning DirectX 9 and I have these test models in my scene and this weird texture flashing happens.

If you look at the bottom of the picture you will see a blue area, that is supposed to be filled with the ground texture I have. So every time I move my camera the ground texture flashes very quickly and parts of it disappear lots of times a second. I know it's not a problem with my video card. What could cause this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has nothing to do with texturing. Your are experiencing the ancient problem of [Z-Fighting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting).

This should be caused either by some interpenetrations between your meshes or, less likely, due to very low accuracy of the Z-buffer in your graphics card.

Comment: Mesh interpenetrations are probobly the cause but what are they exactly and do I solve it by recreating the mesh or what do I do?

Comment: @MisterArch: You probably have the range between zNear and zFar too great. You have to realize that the depth buffer is (usually) fixed-point, if you have a 16-bit depth buffer you have 65536 unique depths you can distinguish. Now if you have a near plane of 0.001 and a far plane of 10000.0, the smallest difference in depth you can distinguish is ~0.153 units (9999.999 <-- *(zFar - zNear)* / 65536.0 <-- *(fixed-point resolution)*). The solution is either to reduce the range between zNear and zFar or increase the precision of the depth buffer.

Comment: Where can i set the znear and zfar?

Comment: @MisterArch: In your [projection matrix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb147302(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Thank you very much that fixed it. This makes more sense now. When I was creating the projection matrix I made an error and put a 1.0 in the ZFar.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @AndonM.Coleman. I actually forgot to mention the issue of the zNear/zFar range in my reply! You should write an answer so that MisterArch can give you some rep.